# EclipseLink dynamic MOXy accessing enum values

Tags: java, dynamic, jaxb, eclipselink, moxy

I'm using the XSD listed below and a corresponding XML. Everything works well with [dynamic MOXy](http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Examples/MOXy/Dynamic) but I haven't any idea how to access the enum type within java.
Any suggestions?
Thanks for help.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema ...>
     <xs:element name="person">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="first-name" type="xs:string"/>
                <xs:element name="last-name" type="xs:string"/>
                <xs:element name="quadrant" type="myns:compass-direction"/>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>

    <xs:simpleType name="compass-direction">
        <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
            <xs:enumeration value="NORTH"/>
            <xs:enumeration value="SOUTH"/>
            <xs:enumeration value="EAST"/>
            <xs:enumeration value="WEST"/>
        </xs:restriction> 
    </xs:simpleType>

</xs:schema>

//JAVA code
DynamicEntity person = (DynamicEntity) dynamicJAXBContext.createUnmarshaller().unmarshal(instanceDoc);
String firstName = person.get("firstName");
String lastName = person.get("lastName");
//until here it works well

//but now: how to get and set the value of the "quadrant"?
// following lines do not work
String quadrant=person.get("quadrant);
person.set("quadrant","NORTH");
```

Answer (score 1):

To use an enum value for a set() operation, you need to first look up the enum constant using DynamicJAXBContext.getEnumConstant(), and then use that for the set.  For example:

```
Object NORTH = ctx.getEnumConstant("your.package.CompassDirection", "NORTH");
person.set("quadrant", NORTH);
```

To get the value, you are calling the correct code, but the value that comes back will not be a String, it will the actual enum value Object associated with that String.  You should use:

```
Object quadrant = person.get("quadrant");
```

Hope this helps,

Rick

Answer (score 0):

If you have on value you can use the class to get all possible values.

```
protected static Enum[] getValues(Enum enumValue) {
        return enumValue.getClass().getEnumConstants();
    }
```